# Finding the complexity of a function

Tags: python, max, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am trying to calculate the time complexity of the next function, `max_list11`, which finds a maximum of a list recursively:

```
def max11(L,left,right):
    if left==right:
        return L[left]
    return max(L[left], max11(L,left+1,right))

def max_list11(L):
    return max11(L,0,len(L)-1)
```

From what I found out, the time complexity should be `O(n)`, since what the function does is `n` times max of 2 objects list, although when I calculate running times I get polynomial growth in the running times (apparently `O(n²)`), and I wonder why is that.

I've time the function this way:

```
def elasped(f,L):
    t0 = time.clock()
    s = f(L)
    return(time.clock()-t0)

def avg_elasped(f,L,times = 100):
    measurements = []
    for i in range(times):
        measurements += [elasped(f,L)]
    return sum(measurements)/times
```

and then I've tried 1000, 2000, .... , 10000 long lists.

Comment: Because you're timing badly. This is `O(n)` and I've got my own timings to show it.

Comment: Whateveryou say, I suppose you are right. I don't believe I did something wrong, but when I computed the running times I've received got a perfect parabole in the excel.

Comment: How did you time it?

Comment: edited with the timer.

Comment: [It looks pretty linear to me.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mWe2_cjM_BsTCh-nD6Jv2wDl3j6PGEJSIKUH9N3-760/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive method decreases the input size by one each call, so it's theoretically linear (since you're essentially doing a linear search for the maximum). The implementation of Python's lists is going to distort a timer-based analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It is linear:

```
%timeit max_list11(range(10))
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.93 µs per loop

%timeit max_list11(range(100))
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.7 µs per loop

%timeit max_list11(range(1000))
1000 loops, best of 3: 775 µs per loop

%timeit max_list11(range(10000))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.82 ms per loop
```

Always use `timeit.default_timer()` for time stamps. Or IPython as I did for this output. `time.clock()` has different meanings depending on your operating system. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html?highlight=time.clock#time.clock):

> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function of the same name.
>
> On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically better than one microsecond.